# How do I make a new dataframe out of the data names on the columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

[Picture of my data of TSLA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvL7N.png)

I want to extract the dates from TSLA into a new data.frame
How do I do that?

`my.data[,1]` would only give me

`3.8, 5.15, 5.00, 4.60, 4.00`

I want ot create a new dataframe that looks like this:

`2010-06-29` `5.00`

`2010-06-30`  `6.08`

`2010-07-01`  `5.18` ...

I know i could do `my.data[,-(2:6)]` But I need the dates for plots and such.

This would help me so much. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe this code can solve your problem. `data.frame(x = df[,1], y = row.names(df))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to me it looks like you want somthing like this?

```
data.frame(rownames(my.data),my.data)
```

if not please explain whats wrong with it